# What's today's standard protocols that use by SSO(single sign on)?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

SAML 2.0?
OpenId?
OAuth 2.0?
CAS?
And others?

I know they all can do SSO, but I want to find out what are all standard protocol nowadays we used for SSO that covers 80% of market?

Anyone knows how do I find the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard protocol because it depends on the use case e.g.

Microsoft Enterprise uses WS-Fed.

Java Enterprise uses SAML-P.

Native (mobile) uses OAuth2 for consent. If you want authentication on top of this, add OpenID Connect.

And it also depends on the STS - not every STS supports all the above.